# Short adverbs used as adjectives

Tags: прилагательные, наречия

My textbook mentions short adjectives like болен which decline by gender - больна, больно, больны.  But it also mentions short adverbs like хорошо and сложно which can be used as neuter short adjectives -

adj: Это очень интересно.

adv: Он очень интересно говорил.

Do these decline when used as adjectives?  Например,

Мария Николаевна совсем хороша?  Я совсем хорош?

I haven't found declension charts for these, so I suspect not.  So then, are these words just super-simple-short-adjectives that never decline like болен?

Comment: Adjectives decline, adverbs do not. They may look similar, but you know the difference by their usage - whether they attribute to a noun or to a verb.

Comment: That constructions *"Мария Николаевна совсем хороша? Я совсем хорош?"* are very fragile, one step right-left and your words in the context may contain an insult, or left someone in a perplexity.

Comment: _болен_ does decline. E.g. "Она больна" = she's ill.

Comment: @Outtruder That looks like an answer

Answer (score 1):

> Мария Николаевна совсем хороша? Я совсем хорош?

Yes, these are valid sentences. Though I guess, you don't understand what they mean )))

"*Совсем хорош*" = *dead drunk*.

And, yes, this one declines (by gender), because it **is** an adjective. When it's an adverb it has no declension, e.g. *"Кому на Руси жить хорошо"*.